# URLs created by Googlebot show up as 404 errors

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I have a situation where Google is crawling our site.  That is fine, no problem, but the issue is that the crawler is creating URL paths that do not exist.

`/events` is a root folder on our site.  Googlebot is then creating URLs like this: `/events/site/`.  I'm not sure what is going on here, the site is return 404 status for these, and then they are showing up in the Webmaster Tools error report.

Comment: Thanks Damian. It is weird because this path does not exist on our site. So I have no idea why they are doing this ?

Answer (score 2):

Googlebot uses heuristics to find what *could* be URLs on your site.   One place that Googlebot looks is in your JavaScript.   If you have JavaScript code like

```
var a = "site/";
```

Googlebot may decide that the `site/` is a relative URL that it should try to follow.

Google expects to get 404 errors from this most of the time, so your site is doing nothing wrong.  They do so because there is the occasional site in which it helps them crawl the whole thing better.

Here is what Google's John Mueller (who works on Webmaster Tools and Sitemaps) [has to say about 404 errors that appear in Webmaster tools](https://plus.google.com/+JohnMueller/posts/RMjFPCSs5fm):

> **HELP! MY SITE HAS 939 CRAWL ERRORS!!1**
>
> I see this kind of question several times a week; you’re not alone - many websites have crawl errors.
>
> 1. **404 errors on invalid URLs do not harm your site’s indexing or ranking** in any way. It doesn’t matter if there are 100 or 10 million, they won’t harm your site’s ranking. http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2011/05/do-404s-hurt-my-site.html
> 2. In some cases, crawl errors may come from a legitimate structural issue within your website or CMS. How you tell? Double-check the origin of the crawl error. If there's a broken link on your site, in your page's static HTML, then that's always worth fixing. (thanks [+Martino Mosna](https://plus.google.com/114158417244913509295))
> 3. What about the funky URLs that are “clearly broken?” When our algorithms like your site, they may try to find more great content on it, for example by trying to discover new URLs in JavaScript. If we try those “URLs” and find a 404, that’s great and expected. We just don’t want to miss anything important (insert overly-attached Googlebot meme here). http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1154698
> 4. You don’t need to fix crawl errors in Webmaster Tools. The “mark as fixed” feature is only to help you, if you want to keep track of your progress there; it does not change anything in our web-search pipeline, so feel free to ignore it if you don’t need it.
>      http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=2467403
> 5. We list crawl errors in Webmaster Tools by priority, which is based on several factors. If the first page of crawl errors is clearly irrelevant, you probably won’t find important crawl errors on further pages. 
>      http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2012/03/crawl-errors-next-generation.html
> 6. There’s no need to “fix” crawl errors on your website. Finding 404’s is normal and expected of a healthy, well-configured website. If you have an equivalent new URL, then redirecting to it is a good practice. Otherwise, you should not create fake content, you should not redirect to your homepage, you shouldn’t robots.txt disallow those URLs -- all of these things make it harder for us to recognize your site’s structure and process it properly.  We call these “soft 404” errors.
>      http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=181708
> 7. Obviously - if these crawl errors are showing up for URLs that you care about, perhaps URLs in your Sitemap file, then that’s something you should take action on immediately. If Googlebot can’t crawl your important URLs, then they may get dropped from our search results, and users might not be able to access them either.

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen that is a really good explanation.